# pyBox2D contact edge too many contacts?

Tags: python, box2d

I am totally new to Box2D and I have been trying it on the Python platform combined with pygame.

I have a bullet that bounces around and my goal is that when it has hit a wall up to around 5 times or hit an enemy it will get destroyed.

Now I was looking at [this getting started guide](https://code.google.com/p/pybox2d/wiki/GettingStartedManual#Accessing_Contacts) at the Accessing Contacts section, and it says that all the recent contacts can be found at body.contacts.
And so it seems, but when my bullet just collides once with a wall it gives me 6 contact edges.

My bullet is a circle and the wall is an edge shape.

```
# Bullet body, taken from the inside of the constructor
self.body = world.CreateDynamicBody(position=pos_m, bullet=True)
self.body.CreateCircleFixture(radius=radius, density=1, friction=0.5, restitution=0.8)


# 4 walls covering the screen. top_left, top_right etc. is vectors positions
border = world.CreateStaticBody(
    position=(0, 0),
    shapes=(
        b2EdgeShape(vertices=[top_left, top_right], friction=0.3),
        b2EdgeShape(vertices=[top_right, bottom_right], friction=0.3),
        b2EdgeShape(vertices=[bottom_right, bottom_left], friction=0.3),
        b2EdgeShape(vertices=[bottom_left, top_left], friction=0.3),
    ),
)
```

---

So for the bullet I put this in it's update method (that runs once per step, outside `world.Step()`)

```
# Check contacts
for contact_edge in self.body.contacts:
    print("contact!")
```

And when the bullet just collides once it prints out

```
contact!
contact!
contact!
contact!
contact!
contact!
```

---

Why does it do this? And how do I limit it to one contact per collision?

**Edit 1:**
It seems like the amount of contacts are semi-random. Varies from 6 up to 10 contacts per impact

**Edit 2:**
Here's a small test sample: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16314677/game.zip 
I am using Python 2.7.8 with pygame 1.9.2a0 and pyBox2D 2.1b1

**Edit 3:**
It seems like when it collides once the `self.body.contacts` just contains one contact edge, but it keeps that edge in that list for around 6 steps. How do work around this? Doesn't seem like I can even remove it from the list, the `del` function does nothing. Help much appreciated!

Comment: Can you make the example runnable?

Comment: @Veedrac What do you mean by that?

Comment: I can't copy the snippet you wrote and run it; hence it's not runnable. Normally unless your code is more than ~2 pages after removing the irrelevant parts, you should prefer a runnable snippet.

Comment: @Veedrac There I've added a link to the game. Just testrun it via command prompt and click to shoot and ESC to quit. Walls are at the border of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the reason! (whoohoo!)

Each contact is part of the whole contact event. It's like small contacts that happen before and after the collision, but only one of the `contact_edge` values are the actual collision.

When I mean `contact_edge` I mean of course the values from the list `body.contacts` as mentioned in the [GettingStartedManual](https://code.google.com/p/pybox2d/wiki/GettingStartedManual#Accessing_Contacts).

So if you look at the contact object in [this documentation](http://pybox2d.googlecode.com/svn/doc/epydoc/Box2D.Box2D.b2Contact-class.html) you can see one of the properties are `touching`.

When I applied that to the loop I saw that only one of the 6+ contacts are `touching` and therefore I can calculate when it hits a wall, which is what I wanted!

Example of the loop:

```
for contact_edge in body.contacts:
    if contact_edge.contact.touching:
        print('ONE collision!')
```